# How to solve "error while loading shared libraries" when trying to run an arm binary with qemu-arm?

Tags: arm, qemu

I'm running Linux Mint 14 with qemu, qemu-user, and the gnueabi toolchain installed. I compiled test.c with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c -o test`.

When I try and run `qemu-arm /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3 test`

I get an error saying: `test: error while loading shared libraries: test: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Running `qemu-arm test`, as I've previously tried, gives `/lib/ld-linux.so.3: No such file or directory`

However, the file does exist and is reachable.

```
$ stat /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3
  File: `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3' -> `ld-2.15.so'
  Size: 10          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 4083308     Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2013-04-22 16:19:48.090613901 -0700
Modify: 2012-09-21 08:31:29.000000000 -0700
Change: 2013-04-22 15:58:41.042542851 -0700
 Birth: -
```

Does anyone know how I can make qemu run an arm program without having to emulate an entire arm Linux kernel?

test.c is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("this had better work\n");
}
```

and `file test` is

```
test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0xf2e49db65394b77c77ee5b65b83c0cc9220cbfc0, not stripped
```

Comment: if running without an OS, printf is the last thing you want to do, certainly not the first program you want to write for that system.  turn on an led which doesnt make sense on qemu, but jamming a character out the serial port/uart to the serial terminal is usually something trivial.  Also you would want to start with an assembly program not C as the bootstrap code is also not trivial as you have to make sure you understand the memory map, where the program is loaded, etc.

Comment: This comes from the arm libraries not being installed as system libraries (even if they're installed as target libraries for the cross compiler).  If the distribution supports it then you can install arm as a multiarch target (like how x86 and x86_64 are supported simultaneously).  In Ubuntu speak that's something like `apt-add-architecture arm && apt-get install libc6:arm`.  I don't know mint.  Just compile with `-static` if you don't want to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run **ARM** without Linux, then you need a different compiler (at least).  `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` is a compiler for **Linux**.  The compiler and `libc` are intimately linked.  You will need a `newlib` compiler with a portability layer for *qemu*.<sup>[porting newlib](http://wiki.osdev.org/Porting_Newlib)</sup>

See: [Balau](http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/hello-world-for-bare-metal-arm-using-qemu/) and [Google newlib+qemu](https://www.google.ca/search?q=newlib+qemu).  A `newlib` port is hosted at [Github](https://github.com/balau/arm-sandbox/tree/master/qemu-newlib) and seems to the same as the *Balau* blog.

Typically a non-Linux gcc is called `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.  The prefix *arm-none-eabi-* is recognized by some configure scripts.

Comment: if you want to make system calls it matters, for bare metal work that doesnt require system calls you can for the most part use arm-linux-gnueabi or arm-none-eabi flavors of toolchain.

Comment: http://github.com/dwelch67/yagbat has a qemu directory, I am working on a separate qemu bare metal example repo, but dont have anything to publish yet.

Comment: @dwelch Right, you can compiler with `-nostdlib` too, but then you have to code your own library and the `libgcc` stuff.  For example, when you *divide by zero*, the *Linux* version of `libgcc` does something different than `newlib` (which resets, I think).  I think this poster is better off with a *newlib* gcc, but you are correct you could use the `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` compiler if you are careful.  This route is likely to get a lot of random linker/loader errors which are often not easy to figure out.

Comment: The key to your answer is "portability layer for qemu" that is a big deal.  Any old arm-none-eabi will not work if you make system calls.  But if you dont make system calls then any arm-linux-gnueabi or arm-none-eabi will work as a compiler, and to reinforce that you use -nostdlib, etc...if you can build your own or find a newlib for the platform then definitely go with arm-none-eabi.

Answer (score 32):

you can run the example by providing a path to the arm-linux-gnueabi shared libs using the -L flag.

```
qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/
```

also make sure the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: `-L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf` for Ubuntu 16.04 package `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

Comment: qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/ for ARMv8 64

Answer (score 16):

```
$ export QEMU_LD_PREFIX=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi
```

This works for me.
It's basically the same thing as:

```
$ qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/
```

You can add it to the ~/.bashrc file so you don't have to type it everytime you open the terminal.

Answer (score 13):

I also met this problem when running a C program with assembly code. My solution is to build the executable with the option "-static", for instance

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -g main.c square.s
```

Then

```
qemu-arm a.out
```

will not report the error saying "can not find the /lib/ld-linux.so.3".

The only drawback is that the executable could be with a large size. But it's helpful when you just want to test your code.

Of course, you can go with the method from Balau(see artless noise's answer). But if you don't want to feel frustrated by something like "UART serial ports" in this step, which is only to run a simple "test" function, go for a try of my fix.

Comment: Dude!  It's 2018 and your solution works for me.  Care to elaborate how that `-static` works like a charm?

Comment: @J.Doe Stumbled upon this so I thought I should elaborate. I have been compiling using the `-static` flag for a while now. It works because when cross-compiling using this flag, all the dependencies are compiled into the executable itself, and not left for the linker to resolve. When you run the resulting executable on another machine (`qemu-arm` in this case), there are no unresolved dependencies, and hence it _works like a charm_.

Comment: @agdhruv, it's 2019 and I logged back into this account after a long time.  Your answer is only 3 days old.  =))

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem by copying the following libraries into /lib but I believe there should be a way better solution rather than this nasty solution I invented!

```
sudo cp  /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/ld-linux.so.3 /lib
sudo cp /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib
sudo cp /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib/libc.so.6 /lib
```

Please let me know if there are other better solutions as I am interested to know.

Comment: Yes of course this will work, but you need to run Linux in this case.  The original question wanted to **avoid** Linux.  You didn't copy the libraries and run a *qemu* virtual machine without a Linux kernel?  That seems impossible.

Comment: I found the -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ option to qemu-arm to work, as suggested above...

Comment: @artlessnoise, there's nothing wrong, here.  This answer makes the libraries visible to qemu so the emulated binary will link.  It's not booting an emulated Linux system.  It's still using syscall emulation.

Comment: @artlessnoise, that's what qemu [does](https://people.debian.org/~ballombe/qemu.sarge/qemu.html/ch1.htm)].  First it has to be able to link the ARM binary against ARM libraries (unless it's static), then those libraries make system calls and qemu traps those system calls and translates then to the host OS.  It's much more efficient than having to emulate an entire ARM Linux kernel.  This solution simply moves libraries to a place where qemu can find them.  Those libraries still have to make system calls for anything interesting to happen.

Comment: @sh1 Right, but the ARM syscall interface is not the same as the x86.  Some things don't exist on one that do on the other.  qemu must do this translation or in some cases implement it; which may not be possible as it needs direct access to Linux internals.  It seems less buggy to use an arm-none compiler.  Again, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.  I didn't say this doesn't work in all cases.  However, it has trade-offs to other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A variant, which worked for me, was to pass the loader library directly and to specify the required library paths using the loader parameter `--library-path`. For example:

```
$ TOOLCHAIN_ROOT=/usr/local/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.7-2013.03-20130313_linux/arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ qemu-arm $TOOLCHAIN_ROOT/libc/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --library-path $TOOLCHAIN_ROOT/libc/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/$TOOLCHAIN_ROOT/lib ./my_executable
```

Or equivalently export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of using `--library-path`.