# qemu-arm running compiled binary

Tags: c, arm, reverse-engineering, qemu, firmware

Trying to run a compiled binary I've extracted from a firmware on qemu, however I encounter this error:

```
root@ubuntu14:~# qemu-arm -L /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi ~/x
/system/bin/linker: No such file or directory

root@ubuntu14:~# file ./x
./x: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

I'm using the "-L" flag, as suggested in:
[qemu-arm can't run arm compiled binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158994/qemu-arm-cant-run-arm-compiled-binary/16722248#16722248)

However, this flag doesn't seem to make a different for me, neither does setting QEMU_LD_PREFIX

Could it be some missing dependencies?

Comment: by the way, it seems to work when I'm compiling a simple "Hello World" without the "-static" flag: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -ohello-nostatic hello.c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the system is not able to find the dynamic linker (which in your case appears to be `/system/bin/linker`, rather than the the normal `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` or similar.

Since I don't have access to your code, I've tried to reproduce this by mounting a Raspberry Pi "Raspbian" image on `/mnt` on my system.  If I try to run `/mnt/bin/echo hello`, like this:

```
qemu-arm  /mnt/bin/echo hello
```

I get a similar error:

```
/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3: No such file or directory
```

I can provide an explicit path to the dynamic linker like this:

```
qemu-arm  /mnt/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /mnt/bin/echo hello
```

Now I get a different error:

```
/mnt/bin/echo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That's actually great, because that is a normal "I can't find my shared libraries" error, and the solution is to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Rather than setting this in *our* environment, we can set this in the environment created by `qemu-arm` with the `-E` flag:

```
qemu-arm -E LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/  /mnt/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /mnt/bin/echo hello
```

Which gets me the output:

```
hello
```

I suspect that these same two techniques -- providing an explicit path to the linker, and providing an explicit library search path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- may help you out.  Let me know how it works!

Comment: Sounds very promising, will try this. As Peter said, I probably need to extract the linker from the filesystem as well.

Comment: From this line: `qemu-arm  /mnt/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /mnt/bin/echo hello`, did you omit a flag specifier there? This seems to be interpreted as attempting to run /mnt/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 on the emulator. Looking at the help for qemu, I don't see the flag that was intended here.

Comment: @dsharlet no, that was completely intentional.  That was explicitly calling the dynamic linker, rather than letting the system find it dynamically.  You can try that on your local system: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/ls`

Answer (score 2):

/system/bin/linker is the Android dynamic linker, so you need a directory with the Android dynamic linker and dynamic libraries, not one for Linux (which is what /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi will be). You should be able to pull the relevant files out of your firmware image, I expect.